# How to set a tint for a DatePicker in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, colors, datepicker, ios16, tint

In iOS 16 [`accentColor(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/accentcolor(_:)) modifier has been deprecated, and Apple suggests using [`tint(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker/tint(_:)) instead.

However, I found it does not work on the `DatePicker`. It works as expected on the `Button`, for instance. I was experimenting with applying `.tint` modifier on different levels but without success. `.accentColor` works as expected, though.

- In the example, I apply `.purple` tint to the entire `List` view, so I
  expect it will be applied to all subviews.
- I apply `.red` tint to the `DatePicker`, which should override
  parent's tint. In the result, it has neither its own tint nor
  its parent's tint – it's the default (`.blue`) – **not as expected**.
- I apply `.green` tint to the first `Button` and it overrides parent's
  tint – as expected.
- I do not apply any tint to the second `Button`, so it inherits parent's
  tint (`.purple`) – as expected.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.date])
                .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                .tint(.red) // <- doesn't work
            Button("Button with own tint") { }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .tint(.green) // <- works
            Button("Button with parent tint") { }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        .tint(.purple) // <- works on Button, but not on DatePicker
    }
}
```

[image: DatePikcer test view]

Am I doing something wrong, or is it some kind of SwiftUI's bug?

Comment: Maybe it used to be a bug, but works well now on macos 13.0 Ventura, using Xcode 14.1, targeting macCatalyst and ios-16.
Tested on real devices, not Previews.

Comment: `Xcode: 14.1` , `Mac: 12.6(Monteray)` , `iOS: 16.0`
Both the simulator and the device do not convert colors like the author. I'd like to know a solution, too.

Comment: Note, my device is actually ios-16.1, however targeting ios-16,
 still works. Note also that my `DatePicker` has all numbers in black, with
the selection in red instead of blue.

Comment: Thank you @workingdogsupportUkraine. I finally updated Xcode to 14.1 and it works as expected (on both iOS 16.0 and 16.1). I've posted answer to my own question – I'm new here, so hopefully it's OK.

Comment: Update: Doesn't work on iOS 16.0, only iOS 16.1.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It seems that the color is converted by using `colorInvert` and `colorMultiple`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.date])
                .colorInvert()
                .colorMultiply(.red)
                .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                
            Button("Button with own tint") { }
                .tint(.green) // <- works
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                
            Button("Button with parent tint") { }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        .tint(.purple) // <- works on Button, but not on DatePicker
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still looks like a hack. And I would like to change tint color only – not color of all elements in this view. Applying `.accentColor` is tempting (it works for now), but I prefer not to use deprecated modifiers.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I hope there will be a more accurate solution to this question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in *Xcode 14* / *iOS 16.0*.

Code posted by me in the question, works as expected on *Xcode 14.1 RC* and *iOS 16.1*.